# how to get dialog red 'x' close button signal in QML

Tags: qt, dialog, qml

How can I intercept the signal of the red 'x' close button of a dialog in qml?

```
Dialog
{
    id : dialog1
    visible  : false
    title : "dialog1"

    onRejected:
    {
        console.log("Red button x clicked signal")  // Not working
    }
    Button
    {
        id: exitButton
        text : "Exit"
        onClicked : 
        {
           console.log("exit button clicked") // this works
           dialog1.visible = false
        }
    }
```

I've tried all signals of qml dialog, and none seem to work for the x red button.

Comment: Have you considered using `onClosing` signal ? https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.7/qml-qtquick-window-window.html#closing-signal

Comment: it's not a signal for dialog in qml : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-dialogs-dialog.html#accepted-signal

Comment: How about `onVisibleChanged` signal ?

Comment: When you click the red close button it closes the dialog with `Qt.quit` call without emitting `rejected` signal. So if you want to do some type of cleanup after closing, use `dialog1.close();` in your button, that will emit `rejected` signal.

Comment: http://katecpp.github.io/close-event-qtquick/ this link might help.

Comment: nevermind my old comment, `onVisibleChanged` triggers twice for no good reason when clicking on the 'x' button

Comment: According to the documentation the `rejected` signal is the way to go. It works on my mac machine. Did you hit a bug? Hard to say as the only bugreport I've found has been properly closed. Anyhow the dialog module is becoming obsolete as new [`Dialog`](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.8/qml-qtquick-controls2-dialog.html) is coming to the party. Give it a try. :)

Comment: I exactly have the same problem. And `rejected` signal is not emitted when closing dialog on my Windows 7 + Qt 5.7 + `QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2`

Comment: Well, at least I'm not alone, I'm using QT 5.6. I will be hiding the menu bar as long as it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Here I want the "X" button to behave exactly like it being rejected. You could call a different signal if you wanted, but I personally kept it to  be the same as the rejected signal.

```
signal yesButtonClicked()
signal noButtonClicked()
signal rejectedButtonClicked()
signal acceptedButtonClicked()
property bool xButton: true

Dialog{

    id: dialogId
    title: dialogTitle
    onYes: {
        xButton = false
        yesButtonClicked()
    }
    onNo: {
        xButton = false
        noButtonClicked()
    }
    onRejected: {
        xButton = false
        rejectedButtonClicked()
    }
    onAccepted: {
        xButton = false
        acceptedButtonClicked()
    }
    onVisibilityChanged: {
        if (!this.visible && xButton){
            rejectedButtonClicked()
        }
        if (this.visible){
            xButton = true
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Qt 5.9.1 on Ubuntu and trying to detect the "x" / close button being clicked in a QML MessageDialog window.  The documentation does indeed indicate that onRejected is the event that should fire - but it does not!  So I use `onVisibleChanged` and check if it is NOT visible.  That works.

```
Item {
    signal dialogClosed()
    property string dialogTitle: ""
    property int     dialogIcon: 0
    property string  dialogText: ""
    property bool dialogVisible: false
    MessageDialog {
        id: messageDialog
        title   : dialogTitle
        icon    : dialogIcon
        text    : dialogText
        visible : dialogVisible
        modality: Qt.ApplicationModal
        onAccepted: dialogClosed()
        // onRejected: dialogClosed() // Doesn't work in when "x" is clicked as documented!
        onVisibleChanged: { if( !this.visible ) dialogClosed(); }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's `onVisibilityChanged`, not `onVisibleChanged`. Not sure if this is a typo or they changed it.